# Linux analog to windows GetAsyncKeyState()

Tags: c, linux, fedora, keyboard-input

Is there some Linux analog of windows function [GetAsyncKeyState()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ? Or maybe there exists some asynchronous function which returns - Does keyboard buffer empty or not ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key question here is: For which abstraction? X windows, ncurses or stdio? Linux isn't as simple and monolithic as Windows is.

For stdio (plain old stdin/stdout text program) `fgetc_unlocked` does the trick.

Comment: `Linux isn't as simple and monolithic as Windows is.`. This is a gratuitous affirmation.

Comment: "Linux isn't as simple and monolithic as Windows is" is an absolutely spot-on comment in the context of this question. +1

Comment: @Cicada: It is a quite simplifying affirmation, but the OP needs to get on the right track: If you are asking "Is the Y key held down?" on a UNIX system, a UNIX system with the right error codes would answer with EWHICHONE: "*Which* Y key? I'm potentially serving hundreds of users distributed over a whole planet, and half of them are probably using Braille readers or okuleles for input."

Comment: Just for information: Linux uses a monolithic approach with its kernel, instead of Windows that uses a micro-kernel approach. Just for educational purposes. I hate Winzozz, and i'm a Unix fan and user with both Linux, Solaris and OSX. :)